# Openshift Application health check

Tags: openshift

I have one webapi application(Notification Engine) which is responsible for sending notification to configured users on request.
I have deployed another application in **Openshift** 4.3 cluster. What i want to achieve is, if this application goes down due to memory issue, etc.., should make http request to Notification Webapi and send notification to dev team.

Is there any way to achieve this in **openshift**?

Answer (score 0):

In OpenShift 4.6 there is a [feature that you can use to easily define your own alerts](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/monitoring/managing-alerts.html#creating-alerting-rules-for-user-defined-projects_managing-alerts) using `PrometheusRule` objects and `AlertManager`.

This feature does not yet exist in OpenShift 4.3, but there you can use something like [kubewatch](https://github.com/bitnami-labs/kubewatch) to use it in your k8s cluster, and you will get event notifications through webhooks.